# Compiling rsyslog with zlib

Tags: rsyslog

I'm trying to compile rsyslog but it fails with

```
  CC     rsyslogd-smtradfwd.o
  CC     rsyslogd-iminternal.o
  CC     rsyslogd-pidfile.o
  CCLD   rsyslogd
../runtime/.libs/librsyslog.a(librsyslog_la-parser.o): In function `uncompressMessage':
/home/pate/cs/csbox/local/build/linux-debian-x86_64-6/rsyslog/rsyslog-5.8.12/runtime/parser.c:247: undefined reference to `uncompress'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [rsyslogd] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/pate/cs/csbox/local/build/linux-debian-x86_64-6/rsyslog/rsyslog-5.8.12/tools'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/pate/cs/csbox/local/build/linux-debian-x86_64-6/rsyslog/rsyslog-5.8.12'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

From what I could find online it's related to zlib but I don't really know what to do add.

Zlib is not installed system wide but in a specific folder and LD_LIBRARY_PATH is set correctly.

Thanks for reading

Comment: Are the header files for zlib installed  and entered into the configure script?

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell the compiler/linker where to find the zlib library. This is usually done with `CFLAGS="-L/path/to/zlib" ./configure` if it is autotools based.